# How to restrict particular Package/Software to Update\Upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, privacy, unattended-upgrades

I don't want to update some Software/Package for ex:FF,
But when system boots or when i Run `apt-get upgrade` it starts upgrades, Why?
How to restrict it?
How to disable upgrades/Updates for that particular thing?
Where it will be located in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

It will no update/upgrade from command-line, and if you need to do it, you can from software center.

More detailed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/260379)

Comment: what do you mean?